# html data- attributes in ember.js handlebars

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js, parsley.js

I am trying to do something like this:

```
{{input value=email type="text" data-type="email"}}
```

In order to use parsley.js to validate my inputs. (I know email can use type="email") but this is just an example.

But I am seeing that the `data-type="email"` is not showing up in the generated HTML.

Is there some way I can add this HTML data- attribute into a handlebars tag?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are different approaches you can do it:

### Approach 1

You can just reopen [`Ember.TextField`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html) and define additional `attributeBindings`, something like:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-type']
});
```

now this will work:

```
{{input value=email type="text" data-type="email"}}
```

[Working example.](http://jsbin.com/ekiBahA/2/edit)

### Approach 2

Define your own custom input field extending ember's [`Ember.TextField`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html)

```
App.MyTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['data-type']
});
```

and use it like this:

```
{{view App.MyTextField value=email type="text" data-type="email"}}
```

[Working example.](http://jsbin.com/OniLiFu/4/edit)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this for `Ember.LinkView` but it didn't work. For the record, this is what I did

````js
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-toggle']
});
````

and my template is 

````html
{{#link-to 'index' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"}} Home
{{/link-to}}
````

Comment: If you need to output the attribute using a different name, you can reference any property in your component like so: 

`attributeBindings: ['dataType: data-type]`

This will output the value of `dataType` as the `data-type` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working to integrate [parsleyjs](http://parsleyjs.org/) into your CLI project, here is how I set that up.  It has a good number of attributes.

Created `initializers/reopen-textfield.js` as:

```
export default {
  name: 'textfield-configuration',
  initialize: function() {
    Ember.TextField.reopen({
      attributeBindings: [
        'parsley-type',
        'parsley-required-message',
        'parsley-type-email-message',
        'placeholder'
      ]
    });
  }
};
```

Created `initializers/reopen-checkbox.js` as:

```
export default {
  name: 'checkbox-configuration',
  initialize: function() {
    Ember.Checkbox.reopen({
      attributeBindings: [
        'parsley-type',
        'parsley-required-message',
        'parsley-type-email-message',
        'parsley-group',
        'placeholder'
      ]
    });
  }
};
```

I am using the [ember cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) project to build my ember application.

Current setup at the time of this post:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1 vendor.js:15554
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a vendor.js:15554
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 vendor.js:1555
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ember CLI, you can install a [Parsley.js addon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-parsley). It adds the library files to your project, and allows you to use parsley data attributes.